# Translating Google Street View POV to absolute browser positions. (CSS left, top)

Tags: javascript, css, google-api, google-street-view

I currently have a Google Street View Panorama from the API loaded into a DIV as described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview

I'm currently able to get the heading and pitch from the `pov_changed` event with `panorama.getPov()`.

I want to have a DIV on top of the panorama (with a higher z-index) and absolute-position it using css left and top to always be at same point in the panorama.

I'm not sure how to translate from `panorama.getPov().heading` and `panorama.getPov().pitch` to the left and top values for the overlay DIV.

I guess I need to take into account the window width/height, zoom, pitch and heading, but I can't still figure out how to get the right values.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: Hi Agustin, I have the same probem. If you found a solution, please post the answer here.